# How can I include the result of an expression in a NavigateUrl link?

Tags: html, asp.net, xml

I need to be able to include the user's id as a parameter in a url.  I cannot figure out how to pass the userid to the NavigateUrl link.

I have tried the following code, but the SendEmailAddress variable does not get the userid from the expression.  I have checked the expression and it does in-fact return the user id but I can't seem to figure out how to get it into the url.

```
<xsl:variable name="sendEmailAddress" select="<%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()%>">
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("https://www.43534353portal.com/s/w/login/question?email=", "$sendEmailAddress") %>' Text="[Change Preferences]" runat="server" />
```

I would like to be able to concatenate "https://www.43534353portal.com/s/w/login/question?email=" and the result of <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()%> and have it be the url that NavigateUrl points to.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple.  Use href instead of asp:HyperLink (see code below).

```
<a href=<%:"https://www.43534353portal.com/s/w/login/question?email=" + Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()%>>[Change Preferences]</a>
```